# How to shout to a stranger 80ft away to let her know that her cards have fallen onto the ground?

Tags: conversation

During my recent trip visiting U.S. I noticed a girl's credit card falling onto the ground. She was walking and did not notice this. The girl (maybe ~20 years old) was ~80ft away from me. I tried shouting "Hey! You lost your cards." but she did not notice me.

1. How can I make myself noticed? Is there some 'magic' word people often use in such scenario?
2. How should I address her？ I considered shouting "hey girl" or "bro" but I was too shy to do that. Or I should simply keep shouting "hey" until she turn around?

Now I feel guilty that I failed to let her know this before she got into her car.